# nginx virtual host - fail when restart with no error

Tags: nginx, web, dns, server, system

I have several subdomains running on nginx, and when i added next one, there was a problem with the same name of subdomain i removed. 
I'm not shure that config were worked in the past. This is what i have found on serwer.
For now there is no possibility to restart nginx with virtual hosts, becouse it's failed.

config tests is ok,
without vh's it is restarting well,
nginx.conf test is ok,
logs are clear

nginx config is placed in project and /etc/nginx is pointing to that folder

I have add that exaple vh and it is crushing event with it.

What else can i check, what may cause such a problem?

Comment: When it's "crushing" what is the error message or symptom ? Are you sure there isn't anything in your default Nginx log /var/log/nginx/error.log or messages (syslog)?

Comment: i found solution by my self, as I wrote there was na symptom. My question was like, what can i check else, or what Im missing, becouse Im rookie in that matter

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution. Nginx could not start after stop, becouse ports 80 and 433 were busy by... nginx. Anyway

```
netstat -tulpn
```

shown what process are runing on particular ports.
I killed these processes with commands:

`sudo fuser -k 80/tcp` and  `fuser -k 433/tcp`

and after that

```
sudo service nginx start
```

just worked.
Config files are fine, and test pass, logs where clear and `nginx` command show whats wrong